# Site not showing up in google

Tags: seo, google-search

I know this must be a common question but I have a problem with my site. 
Its been up for about four months and its working fine on other search engines but not on Google. Its a very unique name so not much competition. And I have a dashboard component to this product and this shows up on the first page without any content or effort. 
I have done the following to resolve the issue.

```
1. Used google webmaster to check that its being indexed and fixed all errors. 
2. Added google site verification 
3. Checked the domain is not blacklisted
4. Changed content regularly.
5. Moved the hosting from AWS S3 to normal Apache hosted site.
6. Ensured no duplicate content, did redirect to main domain from ip and dns addresses
7. Created a google add campaign 
8. Linked all social sites including google+ business
9. Used seo sites to test for errors. The score is 65 so still working on some issues. There are some issues like only 12% content to html.
10. Removed animation from the site
11. Checked it is being indexed using site:fiskl.com
```

I am looking for some pointers to where I can go from here. 
It so strange that it doesn't appear at all and that my dashboard without any links or effort is on or near page 1 with a search for fiskl
The only way I can have any google presence is to run an add campaign.

--EDIT--

1. Improved the page speed to 90% using google [google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)
2. Check different regions using googles ncr (Non country redirect). So if you want to see what your results are in the .com you can load https://www.google.com/ncr or to check in the Neterlands for example https://www.google.nl/ncr

Still 100% omission from results for an exact company search although my dashboard login page is on page 1.

Comment: Personally John I don't think its a duplicate. Sure there are lots of questions about sites not showing up in google but my site consists of two parts, as website and a dashboard. The dashboard is indexed fine but the website is not. The question is about what other avenues there are for investigation.

Comment: I wish the answer above was the right answer but I already investigated that prior to asking the question..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate either.